# Grafana get Graph (old) back

Tags: grafana

Is there any way to use Graph (old) again? Since its depreciated and can’t be selected but I prefer Graph (old) over time series. Any way to get it back? My old panels are still working but when I try to create new ones I can’t select Graph (old) it just blanks out and shows depreciated. For my even tho I’m pretty new to Grafana Graph (old) is just better in my perspective. And why prevent Users from using Graph (old)? I surely don’t think it was because of security reasons…

Comment: yeah, the time series panel has issues with handling duplicated or out-of-order samples; no issues with the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cannot select it in the visualization dropdown but you can manually edit the panel json to change it there.

1. Edit the panel json (click on the panel title, Inspect -> Panel JSON)
2. Find the `type` field and change from `timeseries` to `graph`.
3. Click the Apply button.

You might get an error about panel type not being found - think just saving and refreshing should fix it.

Before:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "gridPos": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "w": 12,
    "h": 9
  },
  "type": "timeseries",
  "title": "Panel Title"
```

After:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "gridPos": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "w": 12,
    "h": 9
  },
  "type": "graph",
  "title": "Panel Title",
```